# Mono 3.0, Ubuntu 12.10, Nginx and ServiceStack

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, mono, servicestack

According to the ServiceStack website, it should be easy to get ServiceStack up and running on Linux with Mono. I have installed nginx, mono 3.0 and fastcgi on the system (Ubuntu 12.10). I have used [this](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx) tutorial to get Nginx and fastcgi running. In MonoDevelop I have right clicked on the project, then Tools -> Deploy to web. This generates the files I want to deploy. Then I have copied the dlls to /var/www/project_folder on Ubuntu. Next I started Nginx and fastcgi. My web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <httpHandlers>
         <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <compilation>
         <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
         </assemblies>
      </compilation>
   </system.web>
   <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 (and above?) -->
   <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
         <handlers>
            <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
         </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have not added XSP to the server. 
When I go to the webpage on the server (remote address) I get an error telling me that it can't find ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory. The web.config file is located in the same folder as the dll containing this ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: share the command line parameters you use to run the FastCGI server please

Comment: fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/:/var/www/myapp /filename=/tmp/SOCK-ServiceStack /socket=unix

Comment: and you're running it from the same folder where the web.config file is, right?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to run from the same folder and outside the folder. Same result :-(

Comment: @Fossmo - Based on your comment, it seems the answer fixed your problem - why not accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you haven't read them yet, you should go through the wiki docs on getting [ServiceStack running on Mono/Linux](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki).

What ServiceStack.dlls have you copied and where did you get them from?
The `ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory` is the ASP.NET entry point and it's available in the core `ServiceStack.dll` binary.

If it can't find the entry point ServiceStack.dll then there must be a problem in the Mono FastCGI/ASP.NET Host finding the ServiceStack .dlls, in an ASP.NET application it should be in the `/bin` folder relative to where your `Web.Config` is. If all the files are in the right place than it might be a file permission problem.

Comment: I have looked at ServiceStack running on mono/linux, and I have followed the description at this location: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-in-Fastcgi-hosted-on-nginx. But, not luck. The response from the server is "502 Bad Gateway". This is my configuration: Ubuntu 12.04, nginx 1.1.19, mono 2.10.8. The solution is running without problems on my Mac (MonoDevelop).The difference is Mono 3.0 on the development system.

Comment: The Bad Gateway from nginx masks what the real problem is in Mono/FastCGI. To find the issue try running `xsp4` from the root directory to see if that starts up, otherwise specify a logfile in your FastCGI setup e.g. `fastcgi-mono-server4 /logfile=...`. Also make sure you're using the .NET 4.0 builds of xsp**4** and fastcgi-mono-server**4**

Comment: Certainly, a bad gateway seems like a different problem than the one posted initially. To try to solve the 502 you may want to chmod 777 your socket file *after* you call fastcgi-mono-server4

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :-) After setting the right permissions on /tmp/SOCK-ServiceStack the page shows.