# Servicestack on Raspberry PI with Mono/Nginx

Tags: debian, servicestack, raspberry-pi

Just got hold of a Raspberry PI and I am a bit of novice with debian/linux.

So thought I would try to get a hello service stack application hosted.

I have followed [Run ServiceStack in Fastcgi hosted on nginx](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-in-Fastcgi-hosted-on-nginx) but get 502 Bad Getway error when accessing the service stack web service.

I know nginx is okay as it returns the "Welcome to Nginx" page on port 80. Mono installation is fine as I have tested a simple application.

I have seen ([Mono 3.0, Ubuntu 12.10, Nginx and ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588788/mono-3-0-ubuntu-12-10-nginx-and-servicestack)) issue and have changed permissions on the Socket file but I still get the same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when Fastcgi server was not running.

Try running

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/your_servername:/your_wwwfolder/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /printlog=True
```

and configuring fastcgi in nginx

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
```

in location section.

Then in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          "";
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

From http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx

Im new at Mono/Linux as well so Im hoping it works for you :)